# SESSION is not carrying over to next page

Tags: php, session

My session isn't carrying over to the next page.  However, it does carry over if I put the next page in the action for the form.  Although, if I do this, the validation doesn't work.

How do I get the validation to work without putting the next page in the action for the form?

**EDIT**

Sorry just to point out.  session_start is included in a header file.

```
/********Application Process********/
if (isset ($_POST['app_submit'])){

$errorMsg = "";  
     if(empty($_POST['app_name_first'])) { $errorMsg .= "<br/>First name is incomplete";}
     if(empty($_POST['app_name_last'])) {$errorMsg .= "<br/>Last name is incomplete";}


     if(empty($errorMsg)) {
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['app_name_first']); // filter everything but letters and numbers
        $_SESSION['lasttname'] = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['app_name_last']); // filter everything but letters and numbers

        header('Location:apply3.php');

   }

     else {
        $firstname ="";
        $lastname ="";      
        }

}    
/********End Application Process**********/
```

Form header

```
<form action="" onsubmit="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="infoform1" autocomplete="autocomplete" class="errorsUnder">
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see `session_start()` anywhere

Comment: do var_dump( $_SESSION ) and see if its starting.

Comment: @Jorge Yes it's starting.  I see array (size=13)
  'firstname' => string 'Janataan' (length=8)
  'lasttname' => string 'Deggen' (length=7)

Comment: @Janatan: then print the session variable and see. print_r($_SESSION) in form submit. check whether all the name you are getting from session exists or not.

Comment: @VinothBabu I've done this on the page apply3.php but this is why I see nothing.  It just says 'Array'. No output

Comment: @Janatan: check whether on form submit it is coming inside this loop or not if(isset($_POST['app_submit']))

Comment: @VinothBabu Sorry, how can I do this?

Comment: I'm so silly.  Sorry guys.. I put printr($_POST) instead of $_SESSION.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
session_start()
```

at the beginning of file?

Answer (score 0):

Add `<?php session_start(); ?>` in your header/config itself.

Answer (score 0):

session_start() must exist to every file.

So if you include all files from index, then just define it there once.

But if you open new independent files, session_start() must be added there as well.

Comment: you send the form without action?